# Upgrade CRE Loaded 6.2 pro version to Higher version?

Tags: php

Is this possible to upgrade CRE Loaded PRO version 6.2 to higher version?

If yes, Then what is the requirement to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CRE Loaded is now Loaded Commerce. There is a new version called 6.5 (6.5.1b). You can purchase the full version or upgrade and it comes with DB converter to import your data over.

Also most templtes for 6.2 will function fine, some need to turn off a few unused infoboxes (infopages for one)

Contact sales at www.loadedcommerce.com to info or order direct at the site.